# How to change the default rails error div "field_with_errors"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using [sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) for authentication along with [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/).

I'd like to style my error messages on my signup form in the style of twitter's bootstrap by changing the default rails `<div class="field_with_errors">` that gets added to the DOM.

What's the rails convention for doing something like this?

I suppose you could add some javascript that manipulates the DOM to rename `<div class="field_with_errors">`, but that seems like a hack. It seems like there should be a way to override this in rails, but I can't figure out where to do that.

This is how bootstrap requires you to mark up your error to use its built in form error styles:

```
<div class="control-group error">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError">Input with error</label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input type="text" id="inputError">
    <span class="help-inline">Please correct the error</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are looking for this<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267998/rails-3-field-with-errors-wrapper-changes-the-page-appearance-how-to-avoid-t

Comment: @prem: Thanks! Was about to link to that myself.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

From the link above, if you put the following inside `class Application < Rails::Application` of `config/application.rb`

```
config.action_view.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance| 
  "<div class=\"field_with_errors control-group error\">#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe
}
```

Your input tags will have a red marker around them whenever validation fails

Comment: This causes in form-horizontal for the label to make the input jump a line, is there a work around?

Comment: I changed the behaviour for a single action by adding something inspired by `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new{ |html_tag, instance| "<div class=\"field_with_errors\">#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe }` inside a particular action method. [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11157784/664833)

Answer (score 17):

Using Rails 6 with Bootstrap 4 you'll need to add the `is-invalid` class. Without getting too fancy I just did:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = proc do |html_tag, instance|
  html_tag.gsub("form-control", "form-control is-invalid").html_safe
end
```

Answer (score 1):

For Bootstrap 3.2 you could use sth. like this (add `nokogiri` gem to your Gemfile):

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  html = %(<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>).html_safe
  # add nokogiri gem to Gemfile

  form_fields = [
    'textarea',
    'input',
    'select'
  ]

  elements = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html_tag).css "label, " + form_fields.join(', ')

  elements.each do |e|
    if e.node_name.eql? 'label'
      html = %(<div class="control-group has-error">#{e}</div>).html_safe
    elsif form_fields.include? e.node_name
      if instance.error_message.kind_of?(Array)
        html = %(<div class="control-group has-error">#{html_tag}<span class="help-block">&nbsp;#{instance.error_message.uniq.join(', ')}</span></div>).html_safe
      else
        html = %(<div class="control-group has-error">#{html_tag}<span class="help-block">&nbsp;#{instance.error_message}</span></div>).html_safe
      end
    end
  end
  html
end
```

Place this code inside `config/initializers/field_error_proc.rb` file (create one if not exists)

This is slightly modified code from: [Overriding ActionView::Base.field_error_proc in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909393/overriding-actionviewbase-field-error-proc-in-rails#answer-13911207)

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using SimpleForm, the accepted answer of using a Proc in application.rb won't work. Instead, you should edit the simple_form initializer. For example using Bootstrap 3.2:

```
config.wrappers :default, class: :input,
  hint_class: :field_with_hint, error_class: :'has-error' do |b|
  [...]
  b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :'text-warning' }
  b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :'text-danger' }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.6 on Rails 5, this goes in an initializer `customize_error.rb` and works for me:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = proc { |html_tag, _instance| "<div class=\"has-error\">#{html_tag}</div>".html_safe }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **remove** Rails' default `field_with_errors` div and replace it with a **custom inline CSS class** on the invalid form element, you might want to do something like this:

```
# /config/initializers/form_errors.rb

ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
  element = Nokogiri::HTML.fragment(html_tag).at('input,select,textarea')
  if element
    element['class'] = "#{element['class']} invalid"
    html_tag = "#{element}".html_safe
  end
  html_tag.html_safe
end
```

It keeps any CSS classes that you might *already have* on your form elements which is something I couldn't find in any of the other solutions above.

P.S.: Note that you need the [Nokogiri](https://nokogiri.org) for this.