# Ruby on Rails - nested model form error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I got a form like this

```
<%= form_for @checkout_form, url: checkout_path(@checkout_form), html: {class: 'details-form', method: :put} do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :billing_address do |builder| %>
      <% error_class = @checkout_form.billing_address.errors[:phone].any? ? 'error' : '' %>
      <%= builder.text_field :phone, class: "text #{error_class}" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Everything is working fine except for the error class. I'm not really sure how I can grab the errors for that specific field in that context.

If I try it like this I get

```
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: this code is definitely incomplete, the `do` in the `f.fields_for :billing_address` line is not closed.  Sure there's not another <% end %> line?  Also, the error is pretty straightforward - billing_address is nil, check that it exists first.

Comment: I was missing the last end, yes. I didn't want to copy all other fields of the form in here because it already crashes at the first error class line. I just want to know how I can access the errors of the form field <%= builder.text_field :phone %> for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message tells you that `@checkout_form.billing_address`  is nil,
as it is the only position where "errors" is called.

If it is nil, it can not have errors-strings attached.

You need to examine your controller and model.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a resource for you: [How to change the default rails error div "field_with_errors"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252286/how-to-change-the-default-rails-error-div-field-with-errors)

From my understanding, erroneous form fields are wrapped with this div: `<div class="field_with_errors"></div>` - if you're just trying to show a different style for the element (no message), why don't you just style this in your css?

```
#app/stylesheets/application.css
.field_with_errors input { border: 1px solid #ff0; }
```