# Simple form not wrapping failed validation field with field_with_errors div

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, simple-form

I am using devise and simple form with rails.  I can't figure out why a field with errors div or any div for that matter is not being created when there is a failed validation.  I have tried deleting everything after `f.input :first_name` and still no new divs.  Let me know what other info you might need to help me figure out my problem.

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div id="sign-up" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
    <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, 
                        :url => registration_path(resource_name), 
                        html: {class: "well"}) do |f| %>

      <ul class="inline-layout">
        <li>
            <%= f.input :first_name, required: false,
                          placeholder: 'First name',
                          label: false,
                          error: false,
                          input_html: {class: 'form-control inherit-width'} %>
        </li>
```

Here is the error_messages partial:

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Edit:

Looks like I am getting a new div class 'error' but I want it to be 'field_with_errors' I tried changing all instances of 'error' in the simple_form.rb file but it didn't change anything.  I'll just have to change my css.

Comment: Does your form div have  <%= f.error_notification %> somewhere? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Also, can you post the "shared/error_messages" partial?

Comment: I want to be able to style the input field border when invalid input is entered.  The way I understand it, rails is supposed to automatically wrap the said input field in a div with class = "field_with_errors" that can then be styled.  This is not happening for me.

Comment: Are you seeing your partial getting rendered in the rails server log?

Comment: The errors are being displayed just fine on the page.

Comment: Actually it looks like it is getting the tag :error.  I want to change this to field_with_errors tho

Comment: Gotcha, this answer may help you. You need to edit simple_form.rb. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26000603/2552070